# How to Use Special Symbols in ASP.NET CORE Routes Attributes

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to use special symbols in asp.net core routes attributes, you can find an [example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/dotnet/#pivot=docs&panel=web).

I don't know, how I can catch the exception with a special symbol.

Please. help. Thanks.

```
[Route("payment/sang/#n1={n1}&n2={n2}")]
    public IActionResult Sang(string n1, string n2)
    {
        return Content(n1 + n2);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "hash" section of a URL (everything from the `#` to the end) is not even sent to the server, so you cannot use that as part of a route.

This part of the URL is called the "fragment identifier", which you can read more about [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), which explains that:

> The fragment identifier functions differently to the rest of the URI: its processing is exclusively client-sided with no participation from the web server ... When an agent (such as a web browser) requests a web resource from a web server, the agent sends the URI to the server, but does not send the fragment. Instead, the agent waits for the server to send the resource, and then the agent processes the resource according to the document type and fragment value.

The fragment identifier can only be processed by client-side JavaScript.

Comment: I have additional questions. Can I specify the portion of the "home?test=name" as a route entry?

Comment: Everything after `?` are the parameters. So if you use `[Route("payment")]`, then you would use `http://example.com/payment?n1=something&n2=somethingelse`