# How to configure a route that includes a fragment?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, routes

I want `/locations/losangeles` to go to `/home/locations#losangeles`.

I am trying to use app.MapControllerRoute to accomplish that, but I am not sure how to provide the fragment (e.g. named anchor, `#`).

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "LocationLosAngeles",
        pattern: "locations/losangeles",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Locations" });
```

And I don't see anything obvious in the documentation.  Is there a way?

Comment: See [https://stackoverflow.com/a/57742792/6630084](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57742792/6630084). So, what URL you expect a user will hit to call the `Locations` action method and what parameter will be passed to the action method?